# Command that allows you to make a role

Tags: discord, discord.py, roles

I wanted to make a command that allows you to make a role, along with the permissions, colors, and whether it's hoisted or not.
I've put the command inside a cog.

```
@commands.command(aliases=['make_role'])
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
    async def createrole(self, ctx, *, name):
        guild = ctx.guild
        await guild.create_role(name=name)
        await ctx.send(f'Role `{name}` has been created')
```

What else do I need to change so that I can add permissions, colors and hoist status upon making the role?

Comment: `What else do I need to change so that I can add permissions, colors and hoist status upon making the role?` is a perfect question to look up on the internet. Have you tried that? I find many posts on StackOverflow about it...

Comment: oh ok @Dominik lol

Answer (score 0):

You can apply these parameters to the [`create_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_role) method that you ran in your code. Here's an example that fills these parameters:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@commands.command(aliases=['make_role'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def create_role(self, ctx, *, name):
    guild = ctx.guild

    await guild.create_role(name=name,
                            permissions=discord.Permissions.membership(),
                            color=discord.Color.default(),
                            hoist=True)
    await ctx.send(f'Role `{name}` has been created')
```

With that example, you can change the initializing values of [`Permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions) and [`Color`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Colour).